# Action Mailer MVC3 and Inline Image

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionmailer

CI am using MVC.ActionMailer to send emails from my website. I am having issues with embedding an inline image into the email.

Here is my Controller Action

```
public EmailResult WelcomeEmail()
    {
        WelcomeMailVM welcomeDetails = new WelcomeMailVM()
        var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/myImage.png");
        Attachments.Add("myImage.png", System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path));
        //Attachments.Inline["holidaymate.png"] = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        To.Add("someEmail@test.com");
        From = "noreply@myDomain.com";
        Subject = "Welcome to My Site;
        return Email("WelcomeEmail", welcomeDetails);
    }
```

and the view for the email

```
@model HolidayMate.API.ViewModels.Mail.WelcomeMailVM
@using ActionMailer.Net.Mvc

@{
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MailLayout.cshtml";
 }
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable">
 <tr>
    <td style="width:300px">
        @Html.InlineImage("myImage.png")
    </td>
    <td style="width:300px">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The email sends perfectly. But the image is not displayed in the email. I get this issue with gmail and with thunderbird. Unfortunately I do not have outlook to test on. When googling i found the following

[#38 Inline images are not displayed in Thunderbird](https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/issue/38/inline-images-are-not-displayed-in)

But i am not sure where to send the content type for the email. Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I used the MVC Mailer, now i get the Image to be sent in the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the MVC Mailer instead of the ActionMailer. Now the images works fine.

But now i can't sent the email unless i use the following SMTP Settings, my normal settings does not work

```
<mailSettings >
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@holidaymate.co.za">
    <network enableSsl="true" host="mail.mySMTP.com" port="25"  defaultCredentials="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Does not work, but when using the following it works

```
<mailSettings >
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="noreply@myDomain.co.za">
      network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="someemail@gmail.com" password="mypassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: Port 25 is not used for SSL connections. Either you set enableSss to false or use 587.